# Access file path from appsettings.json for docker linux

Tags: c#, linux, docker, file, asp.net-core

In my asp .net core web application, I access some file paths from `appsettings.json`. And create a new file there with some content. Following is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "root_privatekeylocation": "C:\\CARepository\\Root\\rootprivatekey.pem",
  "root_publickeylocation": "C:\\CARepository\\Root\\rootpublickey.pem",
  "crl_location": "C:\\CARepository\\CRL\\Crl.crl",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This works well for windows, as it creates directories `CARepository`, `Root` and file `rootprivatekey.pem`. Following is the code to create these:

```
string pathFromConfig= Configuration["root_privatekeylocation"];
string privateKey = textWriter.ToString();
//if directory not exist then create
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(pathFromConfig);
file.Directory.Create(); // If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.
    
using StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(pathFromConfig);
f.Write(privateKey);
```

Now, I need this application to be run on a Linux server. So, I add docker support to the application from VS for Linux, create a docker image and run the docker container with this image. For this, I change the `appsettings.json` as the Linux will not have `C:\\` :

```
{
  "root_privatekeylocation": "~/CARepository/Root/rootprivatekey.pem",
  "root_publickeylocation": "~/CARepository/Root/rootpublickey.pem",
  "crl_location": "~/CARepository/CRL/Crl.crl",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Call the application API to create the files on the given path, it returns the output but not creating a file  `~/CARepository/Root/rootprivatekey.pem` nor I can find `CARepository` anywhere. Seems it doesn't create this path. I checked in docker container CLI. Can anybody help me? Is there any other file path format for Linux docker or do I need to change C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ~ to specify the user's home folder, use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);` or choose one of the other SpecialFolder enumerations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-5.0

Comment: This returns empty `""` for me. This means no special folders on Docker Linux container

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/07/dotnet-special-folder-api-linux/ does this help?